# Error while archieving the project

Tags: iphone, testing

Things I have done:

```
Changed the build configuration in archive to release
Added the developer certificates in code signing identity
Then Product--->Archive
```

I found the following error:

```
 Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

Finally I removed all my certificates in the keychain access and I once again downloaded my certificates from the developer sites and added ,even after I'm getting the same error...
I don't know what I'm missing here???
Any suggestions plz...

Comment: Assuming XCode 4.2, did you do a Build->Build for archiving first?

Comment: you'd still find that option. Maybe you'd get hold of the error when you do a build first

Comment: btw if you are doing an archiving, you should be using a Distribution certificate not a developer one

Comment: I did all what u ve mentioned... I ve included only the distribution certificate......

Answer (score 0):

Before selecting the profile, remove the old reference made in the build configurations for both Project and Target Settings.

**Choose Project Settings -> Build Settings -> Code Signing Identity-> (Release/Distribution) -> Other, clear the old entry. And now select your new profile.**

Do the same thing for Target Settings.

Also, when you add or replace new profile in the Provisioning Profile folder, restart your xcode to get the updated profile. Else XCode will be referring the old profile which leds to the code sign failed error.

Comment: R u asking me to delete the old profiles in keychain access??

Comment: no. dont delete the old profiles. I suggest you to delete the old references you made in the build settings.